# Qsort sort from small to high

Tags: c, compare, qsort

does somebody know how to write the comparefunction of qsort?
I want the comparefunction1 to sort the array from highest to lowest and comparefunction2 to sort another array from lowest to highest.
My Code:

```
   int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {                                                                                             
       if (*(double*) a < *(double*) b)
           return 1;
       else if (*(double*) a > *(double*) b)
           return -1;
       else
           return 0;
   }

   int cmpfunc2(const void *a, const void *b) {
       if (*(float*) a < *(float*) b)
           return -1;
       else if (*(float*) a > *(float*) b)
           return 1;
       else
           return 0;
   }
```

sadly both compare functions sort from highest to lowest. I want one to sort from lowest to highest.
The qsort looks like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(){
qsort(Acal, 4, sizeof(float), cmpfunc);
qsort(Value, 4, sizeof(float), cmpfunc2);
}
```

Does someone see a mistake, or know how to write the cmpfunctions?
I only want to have the Value array sorted from lowest to highest. The real code, is hard to understand (i'm new to c)
main.h :

```
typedef struct{
    float Value[5] ;
double Acal[5];
} value;

int cmpfunc();
int cmpfun2();
```

This is the Array, just dont care about the struct.
My Array i want to sort with cmpfunc1 is a double (double Acal[5])

Comment: Please provide some minimal complete code to see what you do.

Comment: Does your array hold `float` or `double`? You should be consistent with types.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Your code works for me: https://ideone.com/GLdXCh

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly means "*this doesn't work*". What input do you use, what output/result/behavior do you get and what do you want to get?

Comment: What code parts do you need? This is actually all I do in my sort function. From my other Functions i just use the array Value

Comment: You have `float`s. Why cast as `double`? (*Note: this invokes UB*)

Comment: How should we see that you use wrong types if you hide the important parts from us?

Comment: @MarcHammer A [mre] is code that we can compile and run together with the input you use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Re “What code parts do you need?”: **A full program**. It does not have to be the full program you are seeing the bug in, but it has to be a complete program, with a `main` routine and everything else needed so that it compiles, executes, and demonstrates the program. That may be the full program you are seeing the bug in, or it could be a shortened version of it. If your program is large, take out the irrelevant parts and provide a [mre].

Comment: use `sizeof *object` rather than `sizeof (type)` to prevent mismatched types ... `qsort(Acal, 4, sizeof *Acal, cmpfunc);` and `qsort(Value, 4, sizeof *Value, cmpfunc2);` (some people like to add redundant parenthesis to `sizeof (*object)`)

Comment: Okay, Im working with STM so I dont have to use main routines, i just create a void and call the void from 'screens' I hope the Main i edited works, how I said, i'm new to c.

Comment: The type of the array and the element size you pass to `qsort` must match each other and the type you use in the compare function. Otherwise you get undefined behavior. Please put all code into one code block instead of several code snippets **and show the input you use** and the output you get. You can use hard-coded array initialization to provide the input data. Verify that you can reproduce the problem with the program/data in the question, e.g. by using an online IDE like https://ideone.com/ or https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Comment: `Acal` is an array of double but you call qsort using sizeof float! That's a bug

Comment: Further `qsort(Acal` makes little sense as `Acal` is a struct member. It should probably be `qsort(variable.Acal`

Comment: Do you only want to sort the first 4 elements? Or is that a typo?

Comment: @MarcHammer The details matter.  It was impossible to debug your `cmpfunc` functions in isolation because we couldn't see the declarations (the types) of the actual arrays you were trying to sort.  And even though you've now partially provided the declarations, they're still not complete, and it's obvious that the code you've posted does not compile and run.  This means that you've typed in something which you *think* is approximately relevant, but it might not be.  Debugging can be hard enough when we're seeing the real code — but with approximate code, it's hardly worth the effort.

Comment: If `Acal` is an array of `double`, why are you calling `qsort` with `sizeof(float)`?

Comment: Especially if you are new to C, you should absolutely have an C environnement running on your desktop computer so you can compile and run C code elsewhere than on your Microcontroller. Debug your code on your desktop computer and once it works put it on the Microcontroller. It's much easier to debug code on your computer rather than on a microcontroller, especially if it's just algorithms not directly related to the microcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up `float` and `double`.

This shows how to do the job. It sorts an array of `double` and an array of `float` once top down, and once bottom up.

It's rather self explanatory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// compare functions for top down sorting

int cmpfuncDoubleTopDown(const void* a, const void* b) {
  if (*(double*)a < *(double*)b)
    return 1;
  else if (*(double*)a > *(double*)b)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int cmpfuncFloatTopDown(const void* a, const void* b) {
  if (*(float*)a < *(float*)b)
    return 1;
  else if (*(float*)a > *(float*)b)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}


// compare functions for top bottom up sorting

int cmpfuncDoubleBottomUp(const void* a, const void* b) {
  if (*(double*)a > *(double*)b)
    return 1;
  else if (*(double*)a < *(double*)b)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int cmpfuncFloatBottomUp(const void* a, const void* b) {
  if (*(float*)a > *(float*)b)
    return 1;
  else if (*(float*)a < *(float*)b)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}


int main() {
  double dvalues[] = { 3.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0 };
  float fvalues[] = { 3.0f, 1.0f, 4.0f, 2.0f };

  // sort top down
  qsort(dvalues, 4, sizeof(double), cmpfuncDoubleTopDown);
  qsort(fvalues, 4, sizeof(float), cmpfuncFloatTopDown);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%f ", fvalues[i]);

  printf("\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%f ", dvalues[i]);

  printf("\n");

  // sort bottum up
  qsort(dvalues, 4, sizeof(double), cmpfuncDoubleBottomUp);
  qsort(fvalues, 4, sizeof(float), cmpfuncFloatBottomUp);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%f ", fvalues[i]);

  printf("\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%f ", dvalues[i]);

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually i am surprised because I tried swapping the operators < and >. But now it is working so thank you!

Comment: @MarcHammer you've changed `<`/`>` __and__ the values returned. Look closely at the code you posted. Giving your functions meaningful names also helps.